# How to reorder MKMapView annotations array

Tags: objective-c, annotations, mkmapview, mapkit

I'd like to reorder the array of annotations shown on a map in order to create a next/prev button for quickly cycling through all annotations (sorted by date) using a simple iterator.

As far as I see the annotations array used as a store *[worldmap annotations]* is not mutable and therefore I cannot reorder it. I tried the following to create a temporary copy of the annotations array, sort it by date and re-attach it.

(*worldmap* is my MKMapView object)

```
//COPY
 NSMutableArray *annotationSort = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[worldmap annotations]];

//SORT
[annotationSort sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(EventPin* obj1, EventPin* obj2) {
     return [obj1.eventItemObject.eventDateBegin compare: obj2.eventItemObject.eventDateBegin];
 }];

//ADDED SORTED ARRAY
[worldmap removeAnnotations:[worldmap annotations]];
[worldmap addAnnotations:annotationSort];
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any idea how can I reorder the MKMapKit annotations array?

Comment: Check out this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539802/mkmapview-annotations-changing-losing-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the answer in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539802/mkmapview-annotations-changing-losing-order?lq=1) mentions, there is no guarantee that the map view's `annotations` property will preserve any order.

In addition, since the `annotations` property *includes* the `userLocation` if you have `showsUserLocation` turned on (but which you don't yourself explicitly call `addAnnotation` for), the annotation order will not be what you may expect.

Don't rely on the *order* of the annotations in the map view's `annotations` array.

Instead, keep your own array of references to the annotations and sort them any way you want (like your `annotationSort` array).
But there's no point in removing them from the map and adding them back.

Keep in mind that the map view's `annotations` array may contain the `MKUserLocation` annotation so when constructing your array, check the type of each annotation before including it or accessing custom properties.

However, note that the code to sort the array:

```
[annotationSort sortedArrayUsingComparator:...
```

is flawed itself because `sortedArrayUsingComparator` *returns* an `NSArray`.
It does not sort the array in-place.

Instead, to sort an `NSMutableArray`, call its `sortUsingComparator` method.

Using this sorted array, your app can access or select the annotations in the order desired.