# Remove Last added annotation from MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

Is there a way to remove the last added Annotation?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017305/how-to-reorder-mkmapview-annotations-array and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539802/mkmapview-annotations-changing-losing-order?lq=1 for an explanation of why using the map view's annotations array won't always work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[self.mapView removeAnnotation:self.mapView.annotations.lastObject];`

Comment: If this solves your problem, be sure to mark as correct please.

Comment: unfortunatly this doesn't solve the problem, because the last object is the Userlocation. So I thought I remove the second last object but I found out, that this is not always the last added Annotation (no idea why). But I solved my problem now by just adding the annotation to an array and taking this for deleting the last annotation. But nevertheless thanks for your help!