# MKMapView selectAnnotation method

Tags: ios, uitableview, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have a table and pressing a cell i want to see the related pin  how i can do this?

I have this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[_mapView selectAnnotation:[_mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] animated:true];

}
```

The problem is that it opens another pin that is not related, what can i do?

Comment: Then the problem might be with the `_mapView.annotations` array Or ensure with `indexPath.row OR indexPath.section`

Comment: The order of the map view's `annotations` array is not guaranteed.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539802/mkmapview-annotations-changing-losing-order and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017305/how-to-reorder-mkmapview-annotations-array.

Comment: You must be using some data source for your table view.  In that data source, you can keep a reference to the relevant annotation object (or maybe your data source objects _are_ the annotations).

Comment: Thanks that is great!!  I have this code to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int valor =0;

for (MKPointAnnotation *annotation in _mapView.annotations){

  if ([_propLabel.text isEqual:annotation.subtitle]) {      
     [_mapView selectAnnotation:[_mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:valor] animated:true];

    }

    valor++;
}
```